# How do I parse a date in Flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, date, actionscript, date-format

I want to be able to parse my date based on the dd-MM-yyyy in flash however I can't quite get it.

Here is my code:

```
    var arrivalDate = String(arrivalDateDay.text)+String(arrivalDateMonth.text)+String(arrivalDateYear.text);
    trace(arrivalDate);
    arrivalDate = Date.parse(Number(arrivalDate));
    trace(arrivalDate);
```

The first trace will show the date like "ddMMyyyy", but after the parse I simply get NaN. I also tried trace(Number(arrivalDate));]

The reason why I want to be able to parse the date is so I can calculate the number of days apart from two dates.

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass a supported format to `Date.parse`

From [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html#parse%28%29) :

Other supported formats include the following (you can include partial representations of these formats; that is, just the month, day, and year):

```
 MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS TZD
 HH:MM:SS TZD Day Mon/DD/YYYY 
 Mon DD YYYY HH:MM:SS TZD
 Day Mon DD HH:MM:SS TZD YYYY
 Day DD Mon HH:MM:SS TZD YYYY
 Mon/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS TZD
 YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS TZD
```

As the documentation states you can leave out the hour minute second parts and just use day month year. Right now you are passing in the day, month and year with no spaces between.

Comment: I'll give that a go.  Because I am not using any times would I set that to 00:00:00?

Comment: Just set it to that or don't send it in at all.

Comment: Ignore that question,  of course I would,  I'll give it a go now :)

Comment: It works! Thanks for the answer :) I will update my working code to your answer and mark it as soon as I can :)